# Using SELECT result as string_pattern in REPLACE function

Tags: sql-server, replace

On SQL Server 2019, I would like to write a Scalar-value Function returning a string stripped from a series of possible substrings.

Assuming all of the substrings I want to replace with `''` are in table `MY_TABLE`, in column `MY_SUBSTRINGS`, what would be the most efficient way to use the results of `SELECT MY_SUBSTRINGS FROM MY_TABLE` as string patterns in a `REPLACE` function to strip `@MyString` from the substrings.

Should I store the result of the `SELECT` in a table variable and loop through each of the substrings and call `REPLACE` for each substring possibilities or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question:

Here is a little demonstration how you can replace multiple values

Let's pretend the table variable `@Map` is an actual table

**Example**

```
Declare @Map Table (sFrom varchar(100))
Insert Into @Map values
 ('some')
,('begin')
,('curDateTime')


Declare @S varchar(max) = 'This is some string to begin testing [curDateTime]'

Select @S=replace(@S,sFrom,'')
 From (Select top 1000 * From @Map Order By len(sFrom) Desc) A

Select ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(@S,' ','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡',' ')))
```

**Returns**

```
This is string to testing []
```

**Note:** The final `Select ltrim(rtrim(...))` strips any number of duplicating spaces.  This is optional

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am actually looking to get rid of the all the values found using the SELECT, in other words, replace some, begin and curDateTime with '' or an empty string.

Comment: @MiniG34 Updated my answer.  See the Note: at the end